# TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array in OPENCV

Tags: python, opencv

Recently, I tried to use **cv2.retangle()** to draw a box on image. But, when I tried, it showed this error. Does anybody know how to solve this problem? appreciate!!!!!
here is the code, and the image's shape is (500, 500, 3)

```
def bbox(name):
img_path = os.path.join(IMG_DIR, name)
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img_info = meta[name]
print(img.shape)
for o_name in img_info:
    color = np.array(COLORS[o_name])
    o_info = img_info[o_name]
    t_left = np.array(o_info['t_left'])
    b_right = np.array(o_info['b_right'])
    cv2.rectangle(img, tuple(t_left), tuple(b_right), tuple(color), 4)

return img
```

Comment: What error? You did forget to provide it.

Comment: type error: iteration over a 0-d array. the same with the title